# Where to find 3D chess pieces set?

Tags: pieces, chess-set

There are many questions regarding the 2D chess sets here, but I couldn't find any questions regarding 3D chess sets.

I couldn't find any free or paid 3D chess set on the internet

The following chess pieces set is from chess,com. so I think I can't use it in my chess project.

[image]

So is there any source where I can find any 3D chess sets (Free or Paid)?

Comment: Lichess has 3d boards as far as I can remember so the assets must be publicly available. Also it uses chessground

Comment: Perhaps the question should be edited to make it clear the question is about a set that looks 3D on computer screens vs. the variant played on boards in 3 dimensions (e.g. Star Trek's 3 dimensional chess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lichess uses these 3D pieces:

https://github.com/clarkerubber/Staunton-Pieces

The repository contains renders in various styles and resolutions as lossless PNGs, as well as the original 3D files.

Available under a MIT License

example:
https://github.com/clarkerubber/Staunton-Pieces/blob/master/Renders/Basic/Scaled/Black-King.png

[image: black king]

Or in wood, as your examples:

[image: black king wood]

Comment: That Looks good. Thanks you for your help:)

Comment: What a beautiful 3D set.. Thanks for sharing this question.